# ALternative of Common Table Expression for Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have following table structure.

```
ID        Date        OrderNo   Status
1       2018-01-01    123       Open
1       2018-01-01    124       Open
1       2018-01-01    125       Open
1       2018-01-01    126       Open
1       2018-01-01    127       Closed
1       2018-01-03    128       Open
1       2018-01-03    129       Open
1       2018-01-03    130       Open
1       2018-01-04    131       Open
1       2018-01-04    132       Open
1       2018-01-04    133       Closed
1       2018-01-05    134       Open
```

I want to prepare a report in which it should show count of Orders of specific Date whose Status<>'Closed' (Status is not closed)

And it should also be shown from min date to max date available in table.

> This table will have data of almost 2-3 years. so performance is the
>   key factor to load the report. and number of rows somewhere 50k-60k average.

So report should be as per following

```
Date           Count
2018-01-01     4
2018-01-02     0
2018-01-03     7  ( 4 open orders of 1st + 0 open orders of 2nd + 3 open orders of 3rd)
2018-01-04     9  ( 1st date 4 + 0 2nd + 3 3rd + 2 4th date)
```

I want to produce this using Entity Framework.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any attempt so far?

Comment: As a CTE is a table object in memory rather than a temp table, you'd want to create an anonymous object in .Net

Comment: I can easily write bad code using EF to produce result, but dont know how recursive query works in ef thats why posted here. as this will be probably for entire year or more than 2-3 years range. so performance is the key for this.

Comment: Btw, how do you get this table? Not from a SQL database?

Comment: The question is not trivial, so I don't see why it is downvoted. First, OP needs a running total, and second - fixed key range. IMO there is no efficient way to achieve that with LINQ to Entities query.

Comment: *I want to produce this using Entity Framework*. That's not a question. I'm not sure what you expect from us.

Comment: @GertArnold I think he probably needed help with writing linq statement. Not entirely sure, but I did interpret the question in that sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like...

```
var results = DataContext.Orders.Where(o => o.Status != 'Closed').GroupBy(o => o.Date);

foreach(var r in results){
    var count = r.Count(); // number of closed record for a date
    var date = r.Key; // date
}
```

Will this work for you?

UPDATE: 
You could probably use AsNoTracking like below.

```
var results = DataContext.Orders.AsNoTracking().Where(o => o.Status != 'Closed').GroupBy(o => o.Date);
```

Per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/data/jj556203, use of this feature improves the performance when your requirement is to query large number of records for read-only operations. And I guess for your requirement, read-only operation is sufficient.

Comment: And ensure you don't have time component included in date column, otherwise above will group records per each date time entry.